# what should i learn to store shopping card after browser close like amazon?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux

I was trying to figure out the best way to store my product list card after browser is closed, so it won't be lost after I re-open? Or even re-open in another browser?

Should I directly store the list in a database? And we only GET request from API?
or something like local storage or session storage?

I'm still learning to make eCommerce website like amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use redux-persist to retain the previous data and also you can use cache from backend as well as in frontend.